# How to have library name preceding header name on a #include?

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries

I'm using cmake to compile a project with the following structure:

Root

- LibA
- - inc
- - src
- LibB
- - inc
- - src
- main.cpp

I have CMakeLists on each LibX, each src and Root folders.

My project is compiling and working as expected. But I would like to include headers as:
include "{LibX}/{header}.h" instead of just "{header}.h" or instead of putting the absolute/relative path to the header.

Since I'm setting all the include directories in CMakeLists, I can simply include a header with its name, but that's not really the best solution.

For example, my main.cpp depends on LibA and LibB, and LibA depends on LibB, which is a math library. It would be good to know from which library I'm including a header every time.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Root/LibA/inc/`**`LibA`**`/MyHeaderFileFromA.h`

```
#include <LibA/MyHeaderFileFromA.h>
```

there you go

Comment: Thank you! That's an approach, but this extra directory is kind of "ugly". I mean, I already am in LibA's domain, why should I specify inside it's include directory another directory to place it's headers =/

Comment: `#include` needs to match the path.  You can create an extra folder under Root, called 'includes', with soft (or hard) links to LibA/inc (call the link "LibA") and LibB/inc (call the link "LibB"). Do you have control over the file layout?  Is this structure imposed on you by source control?

Comment: @YuriA.Brito Actually this is kind of common practice

Comment: Thank you, @Paranaix. I will adopt that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

*Promoting a comment to an answer to make it easier for others to find:*

`#include` needs to match the path. You could create an extra folder under `Root`, called `includes`, with soft (or hard) links to `LibA/inc` (call the link `LibA`) and `LibB/inc` (call the link `LibB`).
Then set `Root/includes` as one of the paths searched for header files.

Root

- LibA

  - inc
  - src
- LibB

  - inc
  - src
- includes

  - LibA (links to Root/LibA/inc)
  - LibB (links to Root/LibB/inc)
- main.cpp