# Library name to prefix headers names in include statements

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMake project that has a nested library. By "nested" I mean that it lives in this project source tree (*in `libraries` folder*). Here's this library's files structure:

```sh
$ tree ./libraries/SomeLibrary

├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── some.h
└── src
    ├── some.cpp
    └── things.h
```

In that library's `CMakeLists.txt` I have the following statements for include paths, public headers and installation:

```
set(target "SomeLibrary")

# ...

target_include_directories(${target}
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)

set(public_headers
    include/some.h
)
set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${public_headers}")

# ...

install(TARGETS ${target}
    EXPORT "${target}Config"
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} # lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} # bin
    INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} # include
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${target} # include/SomeLibrary
)
install(
    EXPORT "${target}Config"
    FILE "${target}Config.cmake"
    NAMESPACE some::
    DESTINATION cmake
)
```

Now, if I link to this library from some *external* project, then I include this library's headers like this:

```cpp
#include <SomeLibrary/some.h>
```

And that is great, exactly what I expected. If, however, I link to this library (`target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SomeLibrary)`) from my *base* project (*in which source tree this library lives*) then I need to include this library's headers like this:

```cpp
#include <some.h>
```

Can I somehow make it so that I could use `#include <SomeLibrary/some.h>` for this kind of "internal" linking too? The reason I want it is because I believe that it will help me to avoid a possible collision of headers names (*if some other library in the project will also have a public header named `some.h`*).

One [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22160554/1688203) would be to create `SomeLibrary` folder inside `include` and put public headers there. But I am not entirely happy with this option, because `SomeLibrary/include/SomeLibrary` doesn't look awesome.

Is there perhaps some other way nowadays?

Comment: Why does your directory structure have to look awesome? You won't get to use `SomeLibrary/some.h` as a path unless you put the header `some.h` inside a dir called `SomeLibrary`. Maybe for some build systems/compilers you could work around the issue by using links refering to the include dir by a different name, but the solution you present at the end of the answer is clearly the cleanest solution.

Comment: As you know, this question has already been asked: [How to have library name preceding header name on a #include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160497/how-to-have-library-name-preceding-header-name-on-a-include) What makes your situation different enough to warrant a separate question?

Comment: @JaMiT, I was hoping that something has changed over the 7 years since that linked question. For instance, perhaps now CMake offers some convenience functionality for this

Comment: "perhaps now CMake offers some convenience functionality for this" - You think too "magically" about what CMake can. CMake just calls a compiler/linker with proper parameters. A **compiler** requires for `#include <SomeLibrary/some.h>` that a header file will be in the `SomeLibrary` directory. CMake cannot overcome this requirement.